# Is it necessary to escape insert values in this case?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, escaping

i am used to escape string when inserting a single tuple into a table but I didn't find anything about escaping strings on cases of insertion such as this one:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE ...
```

...I know that TABLE1 and TABLE2 must have identical columns (and they have). But i'm not sure about escaping. Can anyone tell me how MySQL operates in this case of insertion and how should I escape strings, if necessary?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to alter it in any way; as long as the tables are identical.

Comment: Is it fair to assume that your question about escaping relates to the "WHERE" clause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case shown there is no need to escape anything as you are working entirely within the database. Obviously the data would have had to have been escaped when populated into table2.

Comment: Thanks. Acctually I'm not working within the same DB. TABLE1 is in a different DB of TABLE2. But I understood what you meant. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Don't escape anything. Use a solution (like PDO or mysqli) that supports prepared statements.

**EDIT**

Accepting that there is a possibility that the OP wasn't talking about PHP, I can generalize my answer to say that, whatever you're using, be sure to use an API that supports prepared statements. If you're using a .NET stack, or Ruby, or Python, or pretty much anything there is to use, there's likely an out-of-the-box API available to you that supports this.

Comment: This has noting to do with PDO or mysqli.  These were not even mentioned in the question, nor was PHP.

Comment: When a person asks about escaping and MySQL, it is almost always concerned with PHP. And if you want to take PHP out of the equation, it is still a valid assumption that he isn't talking about direct interaction with the database, since he is asking about escaping. My bottom line still stands--use an API (in whatever language you're working with) that supports prepared statements.

Comment: Removed my last comment because it was not constructive.

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT INTO TABLE1 SELECT * FROM TABLE2` is fine as-is.  If you have any user input in the `WHERE ...` part, you will need to escape that, in the same way you are familiar with.